# How to get value of child element in table cell with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I added jQuery to an older application.  This is causing some syntax errors so I need to update the older code to be compatible with jQuery.  For clarification, once I include jQuery, `myTable.rows.length` returns "undefined."  The reason I am including jQuery is because I want to use DatePicker elsewhere on the page.

Once I changed `myTable.rows.length` to  `$('#myTable tr').length;` that part worked correctly, which led me to believe I need to update the following snippets as well.

What is the equivalent of the following code, in jQuery?:
`myTable.rows[i].cells[0].children[0].value;`

Comment: You should be able to at least put a starting point together by looking through jQuery API. This isn't a code conversion service

Comment: Where did you get stuck when you attempted to compose this in jQuery? And, frankly, if it works why are you changing it to jQuery? You may want to read the documentation, focusing on the traversal methods. [jQuery API](http://api.jQuery,com/). Note: I'm voting to close as "unclear what you're asking," because of the comments left elsewhere, offering 'explanation' that's left out of the question, and the follow-up questions left to another answer.

Comment: Sorry David, I've attempted to add some clarification to the main question.  I hope that is helpful.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever that simply including jQuery library in page would break your code

Answer (score 0):

If what you are doing works, why change it?

I am not a fan of this, but the same idea would be

```
$("#myTableId")find("tbody tr").eq(i).find("td").eq(0).children().eq(0).val();
```

You would probably be better off with having a class on the item you are trying to select.

If it will be the first input in the first cell it would just be

```
var i = 0;
var rows = $("#myTableId")find("tbody tr");
var inputVal rows.eq(i).find("td :input").val();
```

Comment: The problem is that the old code does not work once jquery is included.  Which is why I need to re-write this part of it to work with jquery.  I need to manipulate values of items in a dynamic table.

Comment: In what way does "*the old code not work once jQuery is included*"? The snippet you've shown shouldn't be affected at all by the inclusion of jQuery.

Comment: After including jquery, specifically `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`, `myTable.rows.length` returns "undefined."  I'm not sure why.

Comment: Well is the table loaded dynamically? Without code showing the issue it is hard to tell why it fails.

Answer (score -1):

It would be

```
$($("td:first", ($("#myTable tr")[i])).children()[0]).val();
```

To select the k-th td:

```
$($($("td", ($("#myTable tr")[i]))[k-1]).children()[0]).val();
```

Somewhat simpler ( i-th row, j-th cell ):

```
$("#myTable tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child("+j+")").children()[0].val();
```

Comment: that is a very strange selector you've created

Comment: Thanks!  I made a slight edit to that, `$("td:first", ($("#myTable tr")[i])).children(0).val();`  seems to work, but I'm running into some other errors for now.  Will try to work on those.

Comment: Followup question:  If it's cell[2] or cell[6] for example, what would I use isntead of `td:first` ?   `td:third` seems to throw an error.  Sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: Yikes. When you start to see nested jQuery like that, you should think you have a problem.